# How to install a European chandelier with a fixed canopy to US electrical box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, installation

I have a wooden chandelier with a fixed canopy that I am trying to install. It's a European fixture so the threaded rod is smaller than what would connect into the US junction box bracket bar. I noticed that it can screw into a larger threaded pipe that can screw into the bracket bar, but I'm worried that it won't be a secure hold. The fixture is between 10 and 11 lbs. Will this technique hold the fixture? Is there another way I can attach it? I don't have room to use chain, so it needs to be relatively flush with the canopy--planning to use a medallion to cover any difference if needed. [image: Picture of fixture]

[image: Picture of ceiling connection]

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the uncertainties noted in the answers you received.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your post correctly, your nipple ("threaded rod") in the chandelier is European—probably metric—whereas the threads in your crossbar are Imperial.  If the fixture nipple isn't replaceable (maybe it's set into the chandelier), you can replace the crossbar with a metric one.

Your first problem will be determining the size, though it's likely to be M10 (10mm).  If you can't take the chandelier to a hardware store, you can just buy a couple of metric nuts in your closest best guess sizes and see which size nut threads onto the chandelier nipple.

Here's a link to a crossbar with an M10 thread (YMMV): [https://www.amazon.com/HNGSON-Lighting-Adjustable-Crossbar-Mounting/dp/B0B9GM3G2R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B9GM3G2R)

Answer (score 1):

If all the threads match up, yes, you can screw the chandelier post into the intermediate pipe that screws into the ceiling box bracket.

Comment: If I read correctly, OP says the threaded rod is smaller than the threaded rod (really, nipple) that's threaded into the crossbar she's got, so it's not a direct replacement.

Comment: I read “it can screw into a larger threaded pipe that can screw into the bracket bar”, to say they already had the needed “pipe” (actually an adapter) with mating threads inside and out, and wanted to know if it would bear the load safely.   If not, then  the I think your solutions are good ones.

Comment: Yeah, it's too bad she didn't give us a pic of the actual nipple on the chandelier, other than the part that sticks up above the level of the ceiling.